# Edit & Continue for native x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

Which Visual Studio versions already support Edit & Continue for C++ code running in x64?

I've heard that Visual Studio 2013 was the first one to introduce x64 EnC for managed .NET code.

Comment: AFAIK none of them do. Although, I'd be happy to be wrong, this is a feature I would use often.

Comment: Works well: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/07/22/c-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2015.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant You sir just made my day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for this comment from Hans Passant:

According to the [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/07/22/c-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2015.aspx) from July 22nd 2015, Visual Studio 2015 introduces C++ EnC (Edit & Continue) support for 64 bits.